# Proper way to order by name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-order-by

I have a query containing lines like the following:

```
SELECT    B.LastName + ', ' + B.FirstName AS TM
```

Currently I use `ORDER BY TM` in order to sort, which seems to work.

However, in order to do it right, can someone tell me what is the correct way here to order by `TM`?

```
ORDER BY TM,  
ORDER BY B.TM,  
ORDER BY B.LastName + ', ' + B.FirstName
```

Or something else?

Also, can you tell me if I need to put the `TM` in single quotes?

It seems to work without the quotes but I want to make sure I do this right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ORDER BY TM
```

Best way!

```
ORDER BY B.TM,
```

No, TM is not one of B's columns.

```
ORDER BY B.LastName + ', ' + B.FirstName
```

Can be done, but first alternative is so much easier.

Qutes are required for reserved words, and for identifiers including strange characters (incl space).

Comment: That's perfect - thanks a lot ! Will accept as soon as I can. :)

Comment: To add on to your answer, the third alternative makes the query calculate twice. Using the column alias as in the first alternative avoids this cost.

Comment: @user2571510 No, that is not true. SQL Server is smart enough to only do the calculation once.

Comment: @jarlh the reason you can use TM is because ORDER BY works on the results set. If you want to use GROUP BY you would have to use B.LastName + ',' + B.FirstName because GROUP BY doesn't work on the result set and therefore TM would not work.

Comment: @Steve Ford. I know. In the case of a group by I'd use another solution. (I.e. select in from list.)